# Why vscode creates a cache of the workspace in /run/user/a_random_number/doc

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the purpose behind creation of cache? Due to the existence of the cache files, it tries to run a file(ex:python) from the above mentioned cache location, but not from the file location.

How to disable this?

Version: 1.77.3 |
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: please provide a procedure and any necessary configuration or code to reproduce the issue (a [mre]).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76099372/vscode-problem-showing-paths-as-run-user-1000-doc